# Enable Suggested article when creating case

Tags: knowledge, articles

When we create new case ,suggested articles side bar should be visible to user .We created permission set with below permissions

- System Permissions
- View Data Categories
- View Roles and Role Hierarchy
- View Setup and Configuration
- App Permisisons
- ​Allow View Knowledge
- Knowledge One
- Manage Articles
- Manage Knowledge Article Import/Export
- Manage Salesforce Knowledge
- Share internal Knowledge articles externally

This permission set contains users belongs to different profiles .Only few users of some profiles are able to view the suggested articles side bar when we create new case.I am not able to figure out why the users of other profiles are not able to view this side bar.Do I need to give any additional permission to the profile users who are not  able view this side bar.Could anyone please help me.

Comment: Did you try these [Enable Suggested Articles to Solve Cases](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cases_suggest_articles.htm&type=5)

Answer (score -1):

You must tick a checkbox on the users record called Knowledge User.